# EOM to state representation for a motorized inverted pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I have a motorized inverted pendulum (think Segway) where i have derived the equations of motion, which are hopefully correct.

I have reduced the system to two equations, one governing horizontal movement $x$, and one governing angle between the body and the wheel.

[image]

[image]

The problem I have is the second order derivatives on the right-hand sides. From what I have seen you only want lower order derivatives on the right hand side to map to your new state representation cleanly.

So my question is, how do I proceed? Substitute 19 into 10 and pull out ddot(x_w)? And do the same for 19?

Link to overleaf with calculations: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xtqcykbxrryb

Comment: To give you a hint on typesetting, those derivatives look better if they're central to the letter. Achieve this by \ddot{x}_\omega, compared to \ddot{x_\omega}. See the difference: $\ddot{x}_\omega$, and $\ddot{x_\omega}$. I know you didn't ask for latex advice, but it will be the first thing many people notice.