# Planar Wheeled Inverted Pendulum EOM Derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I am building a two wheeled robot as a personal project and am having some trouble with the equations of motion. I derived a state space model but when I simulate it in scipy I get some odd behavior such as the body appearing locked to the wheels when no input is given as well as the dynamics just being very slow (~3 full seconds to fall to a hanging position). While doing the derivation I found several resources which were for similar systems such as the cart pendulum and non-planar wheeled inverted pendulum but have been having trouble adapting them to my system. Also, I found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369912/eom-to-state-representation-for-a-motorized-inverted-pendulum) here which appears similar but did not have any responses. To illustrate the issue I've attached two gifs, the left one showing the behavior with my derived equations and the right showing the same model with a slight modification to the linear and angular acceleration terms (which I can't justify mathematically) making it behave much closer to what I expect from a real system. At each time step the total potential and kinetic energy is calculated and subtracted from the initial energy to get the energy error shown in each gif. I will also be including my derivation further below. Since the equations became rather tedious I used a computer algebra system (SageMath) to assist with some of the calculations so it (hopefully) shouldn't be an algebra error causing the weird behavior. In short **My Question** is are my initial assumptions and definitions the cause of the strange behavior in the left figure?

[image]
[image]

An overview of my system can be seen here: 
[image]
[image]
Since the variable x is to be measured with encoders a dummy variable $\phi$ is included measured off of body 2. This leads to:

$$x = r\phi + r\theta \tag{1}$$ and $$\dot{x}=r\dot{\phi} + r\dot{\theta} \tag{2}$$

The Lagrangian is defined as: $L = K - U$

$$K = \frac{1}{2}m_1 \Vert \dot{\vec{x}}_1 \Vert ^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2 \Vert \dot{\vec{x}}_2 \Vert ^2 + \frac{1}{2}J_1 \dot{\phi} ^2 + \frac{1}{2}J_2 \dot{\theta} ^2 \tag{3}$$

Since $\vec{x_1} = x\hat{i}$ the magnitude of its' derivative is: $\Vert \dot{\vec{x_1}}\Vert=\dot{x} \tag{4}$

The position of the second body is more involved:
$$\vec{x_2} = (x + L sin(\theta))\hat{i} + (L cos(\theta))\hat{j}$$
$$\vec{\dot{x}_2} = (\dot{x} + L cos(\theta)\dot{\theta})\hat{i} + (-L sin(\theta)\dot{\theta})\hat{j}$$
The magnitude of this derivative can be found with the Pythagorean Theorem:
$$\Vert \vec{\dot{x}_2} \Vert = \sqrt{(\dot{x} + Lcos(\theta)\dot{\theta})^2 + (-Lsin(\theta)\dot{\theta})^2}$$
Expanding and simplifying gives:
$$\Vert \vec{\dot{x}_2} \Vert = \sqrt{\dot{x}^2 + 2Lcos(\theta)\dot{x}\dot{\theta} + L^2 \dot{\theta}^2} \tag{5}$$
Substituting 4 and 5 into 3 gives:
$$K = \frac{1}{2}m_1 \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2 (\dot{x}^2 + 2Lcos(\theta)\dot{x}\dot{\theta} + L^2 \dot{\theta}^2) + \frac{1}{2}J_1 (\frac{\dot{x}}{r} - \dot{\theta})^2 + \frac{1}{2}J_2 \dot{\theta} ^2 $$
$$K = \frac{1}{2}m_1 \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2 \dot{x}^2 + m_2 Lcos(\theta)\dot{x}\dot{\theta} + \frac{1}{2}m_2 L^2 \dot{\theta}^2 + \frac{1}{2}J_1 \frac{\dot{x}^2}{r^2} - \frac{J_1}{r}\dot{x}\dot{\theta} + \frac{1}{2}J_1 \dot{\theta}^2 + \frac{1}{2}J_2 \dot{\theta} ^2 $$
$$K = \frac{1}{2}(m_1 + m_2 + \frac{J_1}{r^2}) \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}(m_2 L^2 + J_1 + J_2)\dot{\theta}^2+ m_2 Lcos(\theta)\dot{x}\dot{\theta} - \frac{J_1}{r}\dot{x}\dot{\theta} $$
Defining $M = m_1 + m_2 + \frac{J_1}{r^2}$ and $I = m_2 L^2 + J_1 + J_2$ and simplifying gives:
$$K = \frac{1}{2}M \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\dot{\theta}^2+ (m_2 Lcos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})\dot{x}\dot{\theta} \tag{6}$$
The potential energy of the system is given by:
$$U = m_2 gLcos(\theta) \tag{7}$$
Subtracting (7) from (6) gives the Lagrangian:
$$L = \frac{1}{2}M \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\dot{\theta}^2+ m_2 Lcos(\theta)\dot{x}\dot{\theta} - \frac{J_1}{r}\dot{x}\dot{\theta} - m_2 gLcos(\theta) \tag{8}$$

Since this is where I began using sagemath I will only show the resulting equations rather than each step. I can always add them if necessary but this is getting long and showing the full derivation is not the point of this post.

Applying the Euler-Lagrange equation with respect to x yields the first equation of motion:
$$M\ddot{x} - m_2 Lsin(\theta)\dot{\theta}^2 (m_2 Lcos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})\ddot{\theta}=0 \tag{9}$$
Doing this again with respect to $\theta$ gives the second equation of motion:
$$I\ddot{\theta} + (m_2 Lcos(\theta))\ddot{x} - m_2 gLsin(\theta) = 0 \tag{10}$$

(9) and (10) are simultaneous equations in $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{\theta}$. Solving for $\ddot{x}$:
$$\ddot{x} = \frac{(m_2 Lcos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})(m_2 gLsin(\theta)) - Im_2 Lsin(\theta)\dot{\theta}^2}{(m_2 Lcos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})^2 - MI} \tag{11}$$
and solving for $\ddot{\theta}$:
$$\ddot{\theta} = \frac{-M m_2 gL sin(\theta) + (m_2 L cos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})m_2 L sin(\theta){\dot{\theta}}^2}{(m_2 L cos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})^2 - MI} \tag{12}$$

Putting (11) and (12) along with the trivial states into the state vector:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \ddot{x} \\ \dot{\theta} \\ \ddot{\theta} \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} 
  \dot{x} \\ 
  \frac{(m_2 L cos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})(m_2 gL sin(\theta)) - (I m_2 L sin(\theta){\dot{\theta}}^2)}{(m_2 L cos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})^2 - MI} \\ 
  \dot{\theta} \\ 
  \frac{-M m_2 gL sin(\theta) + (m_2 L cos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})m_2 L sin(\theta){\dot{\theta}}^2}{(m_2 L cos(\theta) - \frac{J_1}{r})^2 - MI} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
 When simulated this set of equations gives the gif on the left. To create the gif on the right I simply deleted all $\frac{J_1}{r}$ terms in the equations. I did this on a hunch and can't justify it but it did give a more realistic outcome. This term first shows up in (3) when the definition of $\phi$ is substituted in and so it must have to do with it but I can't figure out why that would mess anything up. Am I missing something extremely basic here?

Edit: I believe I have solved my problem by removing the dependence of $\phi$ on $\theta$. While the simulation works now I do have **questions** as to why this worked? My initial justification was that I had defined $\phi$ in a non-inertial frame which would require special treatment due to how its datum rotates with $\theta$, though I'm starting to doubt that. On the other hand I could have simply invented a relationship which did not exist. Would someone be able to explain what the issue with this original assumption was?

Also with regard to the slowness of the system, apparently I have no concept of scale for moments of inertia and used an obscenely large value for the wheel inertia. Below is a gif of the system wobbling around.

[image: Solved]

Comment: Equation (1) is not correct